# Run python script after another running script ends

Tags: python, bash

I have a python script running that will take a long time. I want to run another script immediately after the first finishes. It's of no use to make a bash program to sequentially run the scripts because the first is already running.

## How do I run some Python script after the one that is already running finishes?

PS the script that is running is running on a `screen`, and there could be more than one `screen` open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I thought of is running both Python programs from within a shell script so the 2nd one simply starts when the first one ends:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    python -m script1.py
    python -m script2.py
```

If the first script is already running, or started outside of your control, you could use the ps command in a loop to detect when it finishes, and then launch the second the 2nd script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
     cnt=`ps x | grep -v grep | grep -c script1.py`
     if  [[ "$cnt" -eq 0 ]]
     then
        break
     fi
     sleep 1
done
echo "Starting second program"
python -m script2.py
```

Tip: when using this approach, remember to use `grep -v grep` before the grep that looks for the process you want, or your grep command will count itself in the results.

(Please be gentle; this is my first attempt at answering a question here.)

Answer (score 0):

You could import the code from the second script, and run it at the end of the first one.

Comment: I can not do that, as the first script is already running